# Wildcard in firebase rules not working, when trying to access data with id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any reason why data is not being returned when I'm using wildcard in my firebase rules?

I'm trying to give access to data using the ID in my firebase rules. I have data stored in complete/-docid/

Firebase rule:

```
{
"rules": {
"complete": {
  "$completeid": {
    ".read": "data.child('status').val() === 'Resolved'",
    ".write": true
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Retrieving data in my code like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/complete').orderByChild('status').equalTo('Resolved').once('value')
```

I only want to give access to data with status value Resolved. But I keep getting  /complete: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to read from `/complete`, but your rules don't grant any read access on `/complete`. Keep in mind that [rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

Luckily [rules can be used to authorize specific queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules), which is what you need here:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "complete": {
      ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'status' && query.equalTo == 'Resolved'",
      "$completeid": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules your query is allowed, but a more broad read from `/complete` will be rejected.

Comment: thanks. But what do you think about a rule like this: `"query.orderByChild == 'status' && query.equalTo == 'Resolved' || query.orderByChild == 'userId' && query.equalTo == auth.uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'"` ? I've been trying this, but it still seem to be rejected.

Comment: Let's stick to one question at a time please. The rule I wrote should cover the query in your question. Did you try that? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, the first one worked: `".read": "query.orderByChild == 'status' && query.equalTo == 'Resolved'"`